# Getting Selenium page source before JavaScript execution

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a case where the raw page source code from the HTTP request contains some JSON data I need to capture - let's say `<code id="data">{'some':'json'}</code>`. But the JavaScript executes, processes it, and removes the data from the DOM so I can't see it in webdriver.page_source.

Any ideas how I can capture this? Or at least somehow disable/pause JavaScript, `.get()` the page, extract what I need from `source_code` and then re-enable/un-pause JavaScript?

Comment: You might be able to configure your web driver to **not** wait for the page to load. Can you post the code you are using to initialize the web driver?

Comment: did you try to use `requests.get(url)` to get this HTML ? `requests` gets original file from server and it can't run JavaScript.

Comment: I would use the requests library then. Seleneium is popular due to the feature of being able to render javascript on a page.

Comment: You could also try getting it with `window.fetch`

Comment: @furas the problem is a lot of automation actions need to happen before I get to this stage. Raw HTTP get is my last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like this is a bit dirty but it works. I needed to use selenium for the first part. I then handed off to requests:

```
session = requests.Session()
for cookie in self.webdriver.get_cookies():
    session.cookies.set(cookie['name'], cookie['value'])

response = session.get(self.webdriver.current_url).text
```

and simply wrote the contents to a temp file and then opened that with selenium:

```
response_file = utils.save_to_temp_file(response, extension='.html')
self.webdriver.get(f'file://{response_file}')`
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me beautifully:

```
self.driver.get("view-source:"+url)
sourcecode = self.driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'body').get_attribute('innerHTML')
```